# How to avoid collection view flickering effect within tableview when changing flowlayouts and provide a smoother transition?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a collectionview embedded within a tableview. The collectionview can have either a vertical or horizontal flowlayout. When the user makes an action, the tableviewcell height changes from 200 to full tableview height and the collection view changes flowlayout. However, the collectionView flickers since there are not enough cells loaded yet when performing the layout change from horizontal to vertical. Also, when reverting to the horizontal flowLayout, there is no transition at all. Not sure why the transition occurs when changing flowLayout from horizontal to vertical but not vertical to horiztontal. How can I avoid the flicker when changing the layout and continue to utilize Apple's transition animation when reverting to the horizontal layout?

[GitHub](https://github.com/sp71/CollectionViewIssue)

[image: CollectionView Layout Transition Choppy]

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    // If horizontal layout, then display 3 rows (with heights 200)
    // If veritcal layout, then display 1 row (with height of full tableview height)
    var isHorizontal = true

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView! {
        didSet {
            tableView.dataSource = self
            tableView.delegate = self
        }
    }

    @IBAction func barButtonTapped(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        isHorizontal = !isHorizontal
        sender.title = isHorizontal ? "Vertical" : "Horizontal"
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return isHorizontal ? 3 : 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "EmbeddedTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! EmbeddedTableViewCell
        cell.setup(isHorizontal: isHorizontal)
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return isHorizontal ? 200 : tableView.frame.height
    }
}


class EmbeddedTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView! {
        didSet {
            collectionView.dataSource = self
            collectionView.delegate = self
        }
    }

    fileprivate let horizontalFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = {
        let flowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 10
        flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 10
        flowLayout.scrollDirection = .horizontal         
        return flowLayout
    }()

    fileprivate let verticalFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = {
        let flowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 10
        flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 10
        flowLayout.scrollDirection = .vertical
        return flowLayout
    }()

    func setup(isHorizontal: Bool) {
        guard let flowLayout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout else { return }

        if isHorizontal && flowLayout.scrollDirection != .horizontal {
            collectionView.setCollectionViewLayout(horizontalFlowLayout, animated: true)
        } else if !isHorizontal && flowLayout.scrollDirection != .vertical {
            collectionView.setCollectionViewLayout(verticalFlowLayout, animated: true)
        }
    }

}

extension EmbeddedTableViewCell: UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 100
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "SimpleCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath)
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: 150, height: 150)
   }

}
```

Comment: You change only first cell's height and remove other table cells, right?

Comment: When the bar button is tapped, I change the `numberOfRows` from 3 to 1, so yes. If tapped again, the `numberOfRows` will be updated to show 3 rows instead of 1.

Comment: It would be a very difficult task if you want smooth animations... any chance you can change your approach?

Comment: I'm flexible. As long as the UI looks great, I am willing to try anything. What do you have in mind @iWheelBuy

Comment: I'd go with AsyncDisplayKit (Texture) to achieve the layout you desire youtu .be/wrctPJxskhI But such transition from UIKit to ASDK might be very time consuming

Comment: On the other hand I'd simplify the layout and will stick to UIKit without the table view, just a collection with some great layout

Comment: The collection view is embedded within the tableview so the user can scroll both vertically and horizontally when the collection view layout is horizontal. A stand-alone collectionview would not be able to produce this behavior